# How to create a vpn connection on a port and only use it selectively

Tags: macos, networking, vpn

This feels like a basic question, I'm sure other people needed something like this at some point however I couldn't find anything clear on this topic and I'm not very familiar to networking so I hope following makes sense (and sorry if I am butchering the terminology)

I often need to connect to a VPN server at work. At the moment I am using Cisco AnyConnect, which upon connection asks me the host server, my username, my password and routes all my traffic through the VPN afterwards.

The problem is, depending on what I'm doing I often need to jump back and forth to VPN (some applications need local network and others dont)

What would be perfect is to create one VPN connection and just keep it on a port without routing anything to it. Then I can use it as a proxy to selectively route my traffic through VPN (eg. I override http_proxy locally on one terminal instance and run applications that require VPN through there without having to jump back and forth). Furthermore if I create this connection from the terminal I can automate most of the process, with something like:

```
function callExecutableThroughVPN() {
  if ! is_connected_to_vpn then
    echo "coulnt find the vpn connection, will attempt to connect. enter password:"
    # get password input here
    setup_vpn_on_port_9876 # pass password input here

    echo "setting proxy to 127.0.0.1:9876"
    http_proxy=127.0.0.1:9876/
    https_proxy=127.0.0.1:9876/
  fi

  ./executable_that_need_vpn
}
```

Then I can simply stay on my network and use a wrapper like above for few processes that require their traffic re-routed.

So in summary, my question is: Is it possible to create a single VPN process through terminal to listen a local port, so I dont have to route all my traffic at once, and I can simply kill this process when I'm done

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using SSH tunnel/Socks Proxy (see ssh -D) and tsocks wrapper. For http(s) proxies I recommend the proxychains tool.